# Client.users.fetch returning "Unknown user"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to code a discord bot that send a message to all users in a list. I am having problems using the client.users.fetch(); method on discord.js. The error message says something about DiscordAPIError: Unknown user, Unhandled promise rejection, and DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user, even though I am in the same guild as the bot.
Here is the code I have so far:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const ownerId = 'YOUR-ID'
const users = ['YOUR-ID']

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is online!');
});

client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.content.includes("test")) {
        if (message.author.id == ownerId) {
            message.channel.send("ok!")
            var userID
            var user
            for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                userID = users[i];
                user = client.users.fetch(userID.toString(), true);
                client.user.send('works');
            }
        }
    }
});

client.login('YOUR-TOKEN');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your code.

Firstly, `client.users.fetch(...)` is an asynchronous function therefore it requires an `await`.

Secondly, `client.user.send(...)` will actually send a message to the bot which is impossible. So you'll want to replace it with either `message.channel.send(...)` which will send the message in the same channel the message was received in or `message.author.send(...)` which will send a message to the author of the message.

Below is an example fix:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js'); // Define Discord
const client = new Discord.Client(); // Define client
const ownerId = 'your-discord-user-id';
const users = [] // Array of user ID's

client.on('ready', () => { // Ready event listener
    console.log('Bot is online!'); // Log that the bot is online
});

client.on('message', async message => { // Message event listener
    if (message.content.includes("test")) { // If the message includes "test"
        if (message.author.id == ownerId) { // If the author of the message is the bot owner
            message.channel.send("ok!"); // Send a message
            // Define variables
            let userID;
            let user;
            for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) { // Loop through the users array
                userID = users[i]; // Get the user ID from the array
                user = await client.users.fetch(userID.toString()); // Await for the user to be fetched
                message.channel.send('works'); // Send a message to tell the message author the command worked
            }
        }
    }
});

client.login('YOUR-TOKEN'); // Login your bot
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but how do I send a message to the user that gets defined on Line 19?

Comment: @WilliamPlays0402 `user.send('message-goes-here');` - [Reference](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=send);